# Vue.js - How to use ternary operator to return html in vue with font awesome icons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, tailwind-css

I have the following in vue:

```
      <div class="pt-2">
        <button
          class="bg-gradient-to-r from-green-100 to-blue-100 rounded p-3 w-full text-xl font-medium focus:outline-none"
          @click="isLoading = true"
          :disabled="isLoading"
        >
          {{isLoading ? '<i class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>' :
          'Register'}}
        </button>
      </div>
```

How would I get it to return the icon instead of showing:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use conditional rendering using `v-if` directive :

```
   <div class="pt-2">
        <button
          class="bg-gradient-to-r from-green-100 to-blue-100 rounded p-3 w-full text-xl font-medium focus:outline-none"
          @click="isLoading = true"
          :disabled="isLoading"
        >
          <i v-if="isLoading" class="fas fa-circle-notch fa-spin"></i>
          <span v-else >Register</span
        </button>
      </div>
```